# $_GET value empty inside isset if statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, get

I am creating a messaging system and storing the message on to a database from a form.

```
<form action = "sendmsg.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter subject" name="subject"><br/><br/>
            <textarea style="height:300px;width:450px;" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Message" name="message"></textarea><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submitmsg" value="Send Message"/>
            <?php
            require("dbcon.php");

            if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])){
                $to = $_GET['id']; 
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO msg VALUES ('','$to','NOW()','$subject','$message')";
                $send = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                echo "Done";
                echo $to;
            }
```

My problem here is once the submit button has been selected, the $_GET['id'] value is empty. The sql query executes but $_GET['id'] is empty. I have tried various ways to get the $_GET['id'] to work like using a double if statement to check $_GET and $_POST but that didn't work anyway.

I am kinda new to php and been doing this on and off basis.

Any suggestions?

Comment: $_GET['id'] is being pulled from another page that contains a list of users in a table. Here is the relevant code: <?php echo "<td> <a href='sendmsg.php?id=" . $db_id . " '><button>Msg</button></a> </td>"?>

Comment: The id must be getting passed in the query string for the $GET super global to pick it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending in the data via the form but you are not sending in any URI information for the $_GET array to parse. Also I am assuming that the HTML and PHP are on separate pages if not you will have to do PHP_SELF as your action to post back to itself properly.

You will need to add this to your form action

```
?id=<?php echo $id ?>
```

Like so:

```
<form action = "sendmsg.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter subject" name="subject"><br/><br/>
        <textarea style="height:300px;width:450px;" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Message" name="message"></textarea><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitmsg" value="Send Message"/>
        <?php
        require("dbcon.php");

        if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])){
            $to = $_GET['id']; 
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO msg VALUES ('','$to','NOW()','$subject','$message')";
            $send = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            echo "Done";
            echo $to;
        }
```

Comment: We all had to start somewhere

Comment: @ioneyed That fixed it! Thank you so much :D My php and html are on a single page. didn't know ?id=<?php echo $id ?> is needed to parse in the id... guess it's back to reading books again.

Comment: I would also look to separate the UI from the backend by using apis. Also I would suggest reading into a MVC such as code ignitor or cake as it may lead down better practices.

Comment: @ioneyed Ah yeah you're right about that. I was hoping to start using framework... but I have yet to touch PHP object oriented... despite knowing java. Do you suggest learning PHP Object oriented first and then framework afterwards?

Comment: Depends on how you learn and what motivates you. I am one to get a quick dirty Poc of new topics done then move to push that knowledge into a project. I personally cannot simply read the documentation to extensive lengths without learning by doing so I would go with doing both simultaneously. Pickup a framework (I like code ignitor) and run with it. You will figure out OO php along the way. Also if you have a Java background you understand the basics of OO that it's just semantics and best practices to do it in php.